# How to retrieve and parse large amount of XML data?

Tags: objective-c, xml, ios

In my iPhone app, I am requesting XML data, and I am getting the data correctly and displaying it in a table view. I have one issue, which is that the XML is about 16MB. It's taking too much time, nearly 3-5 minutes, to get the data and to load it in the table view. How can I resolve this?

Can I split off part of the data first and then subsequently parse the rest?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the below article regarding the performance of XML parsers, certainly helpful for you

[How to chose the best xml parser for your iPhone project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)